# How to display a dataframe multiple times?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to display multiple times dataframe?
Basically, I would like to see the df X time in a row.
I've tried via for loop but didn't manage to do so.

```py
data = {'Counter':list(range(1, 10)),
        'Country':['USA','UK','UK','USA','UK','USA','UK','USA','UK'],
        'A':[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
        'B':[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],
        'C':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1],
        'D':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        'AA':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        'BB':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        'CC':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        'DD':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

       }

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df

for x in range(3):
    df
```

I've tried to use print but I don't see the results as a dataframe.

Comment: You can print df X times in a row using a for loop, it's your IDE that doesn't show complete output. May I know the use-case for this tho?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a peculiar request, details on what you really want to achieve would be appreciated.

Nevertheless, you can use the following loop (example for 3 times):

```
for i in range(3):
    print(df)
```

or concatenate your data n times:

```
print(pd.concat([df]*3))
```

To print in jupyter:

```
from IPython.display import display
for i in range(3):
    display(df.style.background_gradient(axis=None))
```

Comment: I've added an example of what I've tried. I know that I can print the df, but I don't see it in the format that I want. The reason that I would like not to print the df is that I'm trying to use this command over the df: style.background_gradient(axis=None)

Comment: @Naor I added a solution for jupyter